# Front panel usb3 not recognizing usb3 hdd

Tags: windows, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

The problem is the following...
My PCs front USB 3.0 ports (which are connected to the usb3.0 internal headers) do not work with my USB3.0 External HDD...

If I plug it in via a USB 2.0 cable it works but if I use the USB3.0 cable it does not...
The USB3.0 cable DOES work with the rear usb ports, just not the front ones...

I have a Thermaltake Urban S21 case and a Gigabyte GA-Z87-HD3 motherboard, and windows 8 enterprise x64

EDIT: The light on the HDD does turn on and you can feel it spinning inside but it doesn't show up anywhere, nor my Computer nor Device manager

Comment: Are you sure the internal USB cabling (from the MB header to the USB ports on the front panel) is USB3.0 capable?

Comment: It sounds like the front ports are connected to the motherboard incorrectly, USB 3.0 is disabled in the BIOS, or the USB 3.0 driver for those ports is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've mentioned that the hard disk is recognized when you plug it in from the rear ports, I can assume that your USB drivers are functioning properly.

One solution you can try is check whether the front USB 3.0 ports are connected correctly to the MB. Check it with the MB manual. If they are connected correctly, then the problem can be with you front panel.

Check for defects of the ports and if you've warranty, contact the vendor.

Comment: But if they aren't connected then why do USB sticks work...